# Discord py Add role on command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hey Im trying to make a command where If someone types ">verify" it adds the role called "Member" to them.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def verify(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name="Member")
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

That is the code I currently have.
I have already looked here for answers but none have worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong function. Try using [`discord.Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) instead.

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def verify(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name="Member")
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

---

I'm also guessing you explicitly imported `get` from `discord.utils`? Otherwise you would need to call the function via

```py
role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Member")
```